# Application Insights has metrics and dependencies but no Information Traces

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, asp.net5

I have an ASP net 5. I can't see my custom Traces, but I can see Metrics and Dependencies
I thought that it was a problem with LogLevel, but seems I can't spot the right settings:

Startup.cs

```cpp
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration["ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString"]);
        }
```

appsettings.json

```json
 

     "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Information",
          "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
      },
      "AllowedHosts": "*",
      "ApplicationInsights": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Information"
        },
        "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=*****;IngestionEndpoint=https://westeurope-5.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/"
      },
```

code:

```cpp
        public async Task SendMessageAsync()
        {
            ...
            using (this._logger.BeginScope(nameof(SendMessageAsync)))
            {
                ...
                _logger.LogInformation($"Message sent...");
                ...
            }
         }
```

In the VS Output I see the Information msg being logged, but not the AppInsights Telemetry for the LogInformation

```
SenderApp.Controllers.HomeController: Information: Message sent...
Application Insights Telemetry: {"name":"AppDependencies","time":...
Application Insights Telemetry: {"name":"AppDependencies","time":...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was very simple, but not easy to debug.

The logging settings for AppInsights in `appsettings.josn` should be under `Logging`

```json
     "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Information",
          "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        },
        "ApplicationInsights": {
          "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Information"
          }
        }
      },
      "ApplicationInsights": {
        "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=*****;IngestionEndpoint=https://westeurope-5.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/"
      }
```